# Как использовать внешние файлы в приложении под Android на Unity

Tags: android, android-sdk, unity3d-android, музыка, внешние-устройства

Делаю аудиоплеер для Android на Unity. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы программа могла использовать аудилфайлы, хранящиеся на устройстве, а не загружать их заранее в сам Unity? И если это возможно, можно ли реализовать это таким образом, чтобы аудилфайлы можно было просто скинуть в одну папку, а внутри приложения указать её директорию уже с мобильного устройства?

(желательно без плагинов, но если иначе никак, лучше чем ничего)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/ImportingAssets.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/AudioFiles.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

Это должно помочь, хоть и не полностью решает проблему.